# Column data type DT_WSTR is not supported by the PipelineBuffer class

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I always receive this error everytime I run my SSIS using command line dtexec but this doesnt occur if I use the SSIS Data Tool Environment.

I initial installed MSSQL 2014 Express but the SSIS I created on my development environment did not work so I need to ask my Client to install a standard version and they installed MSSQL 2016 Standard.

I have to run DTExec on the correct directory (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn) for it to work properly but on the script step it fails with error

> Column data type DT_WSTR is not supported by the PipelineBuffer Class